# Введение в объекты. Повторное использование реализации

Tags: java

Теория гласит, что повторное использование класса - это прямое использование объектов этого класса. Новый класс может содержать любое число объектов любого типа(класса), в любой комбинации, которая нужна в новом классе. Здесь все понятно. Но этот же источник знаний утверждает, что новый класс может состоять из существующих классов, и называет эту концепцию - композицией. Как понять? Эти утверждения разные по форме и содержанию, или одно и то же?

Answer (score 2):

Какое-то излишне формализованное словоблудие, ей-богу. Идея композиции очень проста - класс может включать в себя объекты других классов (как автомобиль состоит из различных запчастей). При этом уничтожение экземпляра этого класса ведет к уничтожению объектов, входящих в его состав

Comment: Спасибо! Ваш ответ заставил меня задуматься. Буду рыть ещё в Гугле.

Answer (score 0):

> новый класс может состоять из существующих классов

Неверно. Объект класса может содержать в себе [ссылки на] объекты существующих классов. Но не «состоять» из них.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что самый уважаемый  участник форума обратил своё внимание на мой вопрос.

Comment: @vobla: Насчёт «самый уважаемый» не уверен, самый активный — это да.